# Convert a string into closure in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, closures, railo

I have a very basic question.  Is it possible to convert a string into a closure?  I tried evaluate() but it didn't work.

```
evaluate( "myFunction = function(val){ return dollarFormat( val ); }" );
```

What I have in mind is to save custom functions in the database as string and then run it as needed.

Thank you!

Edit: Just to clarify: I want to be able to save "function(val){ return dollarFormat( val ); }" as a string in database and be able to convert it into a functioning closure.

Comment: Is this for ColdFusion, or Railo, or both? I cannae get it to work on either, but if it's for Railo you should be able to get an authoritative answer from the Railo engineers if you ask on their Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/railo

Comment: For the moment it's for a Railo project, but I'd like to use it for ColdFusion too.  I will post it there.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, here's the answer from Railo Group:  Save the string in a RAM file and then include that file.

Comment: In theory that should work fine via CF too.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with user2943775 answer:

```
<cfscript>
FileWrite("/ram/UDFs.cfm", "<cfset myFunction = function(val){ return dollarFormat( val ); }>")
include template="/ram/UDFs.cfm";
writedump(myFunction(10));
</cfscript>
```

And in your Application.cfc

```
component {
    this.mappings["/ram"] = "ram://";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar solution, though I was unable to use the in-memory filesystem due to security restrictions. In my Application.cfc, I added the following mapping:

```
this.mappings = {
    "/models" = "#APP_ROOT_PATH#cfcs/models",
    "/utils" = "#APP_ROOT_PATH#cfcs/utils",
    "/modules" = "#APP_ROOT_PATH#_modules",
    "/components" = "#APP_ROOT_PATH#cfcs",
    "/udfs" = "#APP_ROOT_PATH#includes/udfs" // path for global (and temporary) UDFs
};
```

The UDF I created is as follows:

```
/**
 * Takes a string representation of a function and returns it as a Closure
 * @output false
 * @return Closure
 */
private any function toClosure (required string closure) {
    local.id = replace(createUUID(), "-", "", "all");
    local.udfpath = "/udfs/udf#id#.cfm";
    local.script = "<cfscript>local.fn#id# = #closure#;</cfscript>";

    try {
        fileWrite(expandPath(udfPath), script);
        include udfpath;
    } catch (any e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            fileDelete(expandPath(udfPath));
        } catch (any e) {}
    }

    if (!structkeyExists(local, "fn#id#") || !isClosure(local["fn#id#"])) {
        throw (message="Unable to compile closure");    
    }

    // return the closure
    return local["fn#id#"];         
}
```

And the result:

```
myFn = toClosure("function (num) { return num + 1; }");
myFn(1); // returns 2
```